# Why is my ref always null even though I'm setting it to a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So basically I have 2 pieces, the sidebar, then the opener. I'm trying to setup a ref that will connect the sidebar to the current opener. The opener is a functional component, and no matter what I do the current value is null. Am I missing something? I'm just trying to resize a component. My goal is to be able to resize the shown sidebar with the opener.

Here's part of the Render function.

```
render() {
    const { selected, isSidebar, selectedType, search, active } = this.state;
    const { pending, callback, resource } = this.props;
    const pendingLengh = pending ? pending.length : 0;
    const callbackLength = callback ? callback.length : 0;
    const isResource = !resource || !Object.keys(resource).length;

    return (
      <div className="newPatientPage mainPage">
        {this.renderMetadata()}
        <SubTopBar
          title="New Patient Processing"
          noLeftSide={true}
          subStatus={this.getStatus(pendingLengh, callbackLength)}
          isBarcode={!isResource}
          sideComponent={this.renderSideComponent()}
        />
        {
          active ?
            <SnapshotSideBar
              ref={this.sidebarRef}
              patientResource={this.props.patientResource}
              isShow={isSidebar}
              settup={this.state.settup}
              isScan={true}
              handleCloseSidebar={this.handleCloseSidebar}
            /> :
            <NewPatientSideBar
              ref={this.sidebarRef}
              stepProps={this.state.stepProps}
              selected={selected}
              isShow={isSidebar}
              handleCloseSidebar={this.handleCloseSidebar}
            />
        }

        <SidebarExtension sidebarToggle={this.toggleSidebar} sidebarReference={this.sidebarRef} sidebarState={isSidebar}/>
```

Here's the SidebarExtension component

```
const SidebarExtension = ({
  sidebarToggle,
  sidebarReference,
  sidebarState,
  ...restProps
}) => {
  const [xPos, setXPos] = useState(0);
  const [width, setWidth] = useState();
  const [openerPosition, setOpenerPosition] = useState(50);
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const toggleSidebar = () => {
    sidebarToggle();
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsOpen(sidebarState);
  }, [sidebarState])

  if ((!isOpen && !sidebarState)) {
    return (
      <>
        <div
          className="resizeHandle"
          style={{
            right: "0Px",
          }}
          onClick={toggleSidebar}
        >
          <LeftCharvenSVG />
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div
        className="resizeHandle active"
        onClick={toggleSidebar}
        onMouseDown={startResize}
      >
        <LeftCharvenSVG />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default SidebarExtension;
```

Here's what the constructor looks like.
[Main Constructor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kbas5.png)

Comment: In your constructor of the class component, did you do this.sidebarRef = React.createRef();

Comment: @RonaldM.Kasendwa Yes. I updated my post with it.

Comment: What do SnapshotSideBar and NewPatientSideBar do with the ref? For example, are the class components? function components? with/without forwardRef?

Comment: @NicholasTower They just pass the ref to the returned element.

Comment: `They just pass the ref to the returned element` I'm sure that's the intent, but if you'd like me to check why it isn't working, i'll need to know more details.

Comment: @ZacharySeebeck referring to the docs https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html you can wrap your function component in React.forwardRef()

Answer (score 0):

From the docs https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html you need to wrap your functional component in React.forwardRef()

Example

```js
const FancyButton = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <button ref={ref} className="FancyButton">
    {props.children}
  </button>
));

// You can now get a ref directly to the DOM button:
const ref = React.createRef();
<FancyButton ref={ref}>Click me!</FancyButton>;
```

In your case that would be:

```js
const SidebarExtension = React.forwardRef(({
  sidebarToggle,
  sidebarReference,
  sidebarState,
  ...restProps
}, ref) => {
  const [xPos, setXPos] = useState(0);
  const [width, setWidth] = useState();
  const [openerPosition, setOpenerPosition] = useState(50);
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const toggleSidebar = () => {
    sidebarToggle();
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsOpen(sidebarState);
  }, [sidebarState])

  if ((!isOpen && !sidebarState)) {
    return (
      <>
        <div
          className="resizeHandle"
          style={{
            right: "0Px",
          }}
          ref={ref}
          onClick={toggleSidebar}
        >
          <LeftCharvenSVG />
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div
        className="resizeHandle active"
        onClick={toggleSidebar}
        onMouseDown={startResize}
      >
        <LeftCharvenSVG />
      </div>
    </>
  );
});

export default SidebarExtension;
```